# Eclipse shows 4.0+ Buttons but not on Device

Tags: android, eclipse

I was not able to find a solution for this and the things I tried didn't worked..

I have a Android Project in Eclipse ADT. I specified minSdkVersion="15 in the Manifest and I also set this Project to 4.0.3 from the beginning. My Layout displays perfectly in Eclipse but when I upload the App to my Device(s) (Android 4.3 and 4.2.2) it shows the pre-ICS buttons. See attached files..

On Eclipse it looks like this: 
(Sorry I can't insert the pictures directly because as a new user I have no points)

[image]

On my device:

> [image]

Any clue what the problem could be? I also checked the Project Properties and set the build target to Android 4.0.3 but without effect.

Comment: Changing the app theme may solve it.

Comment: Already tried that, unfortunately with no effect. (only in the "WYSIWYG" editor of Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also use targetSdkVersion parameter to target the latest SDK

Comment: jep, targetSdkVersion is specified - no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check the Theme of the actives in manifest?

Read about also in: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme

Comment: yes, they are all specified by android:theme="@style/AppTheme" which relies on <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">. Maybe i should mention that the buttons are on a fullscreen dialog overlay..

Comment: Not quite sure why but it seems to work now for activitys. However, the dialog overlay on which i have 5 buttons are still not in "ICS style" BTW: Can't give you reputation because of the lack of points..